# Asp.net MVC TextArea

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to size the TextArea and assign Model Value to it in Asp.net Mvc

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <%=Html.TextAreaFor(
        m => m.Description, 15, 20, 
        new RouteValueDictionary(new { @class = "someClass"}))%>
```

Edit:
This wont work as far as I know

```
<%=Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, new { cols = "20", rows = "15" })%>
```

because of this:

```
private const int TextAreaRows = 2;
private const int TextAreaColumns = 20;

// ...





     public static string TextArea(
                this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, 
                IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes) {
            Dictionary<string, object> implicitAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            implicitAttributes.Add("rows", TextAreaRows.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            implicitAttributes.Add("cols", TextAreaColumns.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            return TextAreaHelper(htmlHelper, name, true /* useViewData */, null /* value */, implicitAttributes, null /* explicitParameters */, htmlAttributes);

}
```

Comment: For your 1st example: <%= Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Description, 15, 20, null) %>

Comment: it does't matter add or remove dictionary=) I think question author can handle this=)

Answer (score 24):

I found a simple away to achieve this.

Using models annotation razor will be smart enough to generate the `textarea`.

**Model:**

```
[DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
public string Comments { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you have a strongly typed view to some model class you could use the following:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SomeProperty, new { rows = "20", cols = "10" }) %>
```

or:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SomeProperty, 20, 10, new { @class = "foo" }) %>
```

Comment: For your 2nd example: <%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.SomeProperty, 20, 10, null) %>

Answer (score 1):

**Pitfall** is `@Html.TextAreaFor` because it has no overload which allow you assigning a Model Value.

*Example 1* :

```
 @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Language, 6, 40, new { @class = "form-control",@value="Tft.WebRole.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage"}
```

Example 1 wont raise exception and wont show any text. Let it down.

**Solution** :

use `@Html.TextArea` instead

*Example 2:*

```
@Html.TextArea("Language", Tft.WebRole.Properties.Settings.Default.DefaultLanguage, 6, 40, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

**Advice :**

You should let down Aspx too because Razor is lighter and equivalent syntax.

Just use `@` instead of `<%= %>.`